# Elasticsearch apply condintions in query on basis of results count

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Is there any way in Elasticsearch for following type of outcome

"Apply first condition, if no results found then apply next conditions and so on.."

I am aware of basics of ES queries. I know this can be done by querying again and again on results basis but I want to do this in single query for the sake of time and efficiency.

Here is my current query

```
GET_search{
"query": {
"filtered": {
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "geo_bounding_box": {
            "location": {
              "top_left": {
                "lat": 28.6143519,
                "lon": -81.50773
              },
              "bottom_right": {
                "lat": 28.3479859,
                "lon": -81.22977
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
},
"size": 10,
"from": 0,
"sort": {
  "search_score": {
    "order": "desc"
  }
}
}
```

Now what I want to do is, if this query hits zero results then this should search for another increased set of `lat lon` bounds. I can do this by requering elasticsearch but it will be an inefficient way.

I want to know if is this possible in elasticsearch?

Comment: What you basically want is a `bool/should` but with a guaranteed order of the should clauses, right?

Comment: Why is the order relevant in this case?

Comment: _"but with a guaranteed order of the should clauses"_ @Val I didn't get this.I have updated my question. May be now you can better understand my problem. Thanks